# Azure deployment via local repository

Tags: git, azure, azure-deployment

I am trying to deploy to azure via local repository.

```
git push --set-upstream azure master
```

In console, I see

```
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id 'bfe24a411c'.
```

The commit id isn't most recent.

```
git show
commit 429c7abcede0cd8874b70f2c37ea8f8e3e2d57e1 (HEAD -> CoreMigration, origin/CoreMigration)
```

Why does pushing old commit?

Update:

I have existing code repository hosted at bitbucket. The deployment from bitbucket takes too long, so I want to try to deploy form Local repository.  So,  I have a couple remotes. I followed 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git . and added azure as remote.

Comment: As you just mentioned just sample git command, it is hard to say why. You could follow the [Local Git Deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git) tutorial.

Comment: That the tutorial which I followed.. I could post any output of any command..where should I start my debug?

Comment: @SimeonGrigorovich can you run git rev-parse master git rev-parse origin/master git rev-parse azure/master they will give you the commits of each branch and mabe we can figure out whats going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that your most recent commit is not on the master branch.

> git show
>   commit 429c7abcede0cd8874b70f2c37ea8f8e3e2d57e1 (HEAD -> CoreMigration, origin/CoreMigration)

from what you posted here your head is on a branch called CoreMigration.  so running git push azure master will only push to master branch to the azure repo.

you need to merge your CoreMigration branch into master and then push to the azure remote